# The space of paths

Tags: geometry, reference-request, differential-topology

Let $ (M,g) $ be a compact Riemannian manifold, and let the path space $ \Omega $ of $ M $ be the set of equivalence class of smooth maps $ \gamma : [0,1] \rightarrow M $ (equivalent under re-parametrization). What is that natural notion of smoothness on this space and of functions $ \Omega \rightarrow \mathbb{R} $? Where can I read about this?

I have some vague ideas about this. What I would like to capture is: given a sufficiently nice coordinate system $ U \in \mathbb{R}^n $, the space of paths that are straight line segments can be thought of as $ U \times U $, and the notion of smooth function on the space of line segments is just notion of smooth functions on $ U \times U $.

Comment: Does your notion of re-parametrization allow one to flip the endpoints? $\;$

Comment: In Milnor's Morse theory book, he does something similar, but instead of considering the entire path space, he considers finite dimensional approximations of it.  He approximates the path space in a similar way as your "vague idea".

Comment: Thanks Jason. Milnor uses the space $ M^n $ as an approximation to the path space, where an element of $ M^n $ corresponds to the path of broken geodesics going through the $ n $ points. I wish you would post your comment as an answer so I could vote you. Is there another reference for this.